# As a customer user, is it possible to delete own posts with comments in the community?

Tags: customer-community, post

Is it possible to delete own posts with answers on below as a customer user in the community?

Comment: Does this answer your question? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_chatter_threaded_discussions_delete_thread.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

If the user has the permission of it, yes. I can check it in the setup option, searching the "profile" option. Then you can select the profile of the customer user and check the objects that they have access to delete.

Comment: The thing is that a post is not an object, it is just a question posted in the community site.